# Getting my Filipino boyfriend a UK visa

Tags: visas, uk, customs-and-immigration, criminal-records

My Filipino boyfriend wants to visit me in the UK. I have given all my documents showing that I own a property, and that I can support him (salary proof and bank account), plus a letter explaining and inviting him over. However this may not be the right way to help him get a visa.

He is in between jobs and has just opened a bank account. He wishes to stay for 2-4 weeks only and I will support him 100%. He will start a job before he applies for a visa, and will rent a place, so he will eventually be able to show income, rent and living expenses. Eventually we want to live together in the UK and get married but not until 2019.

Any suggestions please? I really need him with me at Christmas.

Comment: Wow, wait for a second hold on. You said that you want him for only 2-4 week visit. If you want to get married and live here, that requires a whole other answer and visa. Can you please update your question with all the relevant details so we can help you best?

Comment: @Harry53 start by updating the question with all relevant details, as this clearly isn't about having a friend visit as it started, but a much bigger plan of getting married and living together in the uk. And that has a whole different process to it.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/57482/discussion-on-question-by-harry53-getting-my-filipino-boyfriend-a-uk-visa-approv).

Comment: My gay friend, who is an Asian gay guy and married to a Brit, has given me an introduction to a specialist Immigration lawyer, who will, I trust, tell me exactly how to play this. Thanks again to you all

Answer (score 5):

To answer your original question, as long as your criminal history is not a serious one or involving deceit, dishonesty or immigration offenses then it shouldn't have an impact on you as a sponsor. But your boyfriend's application (thanks for clarifying that bit) will be in serious jeopardy for multiple reasons.

First, your boyfriend is currently unemployed and is living with his family. Additionally, I figure that he doesn't have someone depending on his income, like a wife or children, which means that it is very little he can show as proof that he will go back to the Philippines after traveling to the UK. That part can only be fixed by him finding a stable employment and have obligations back home (think rent, work, friends).

Lack of the above alone is likely to attract a refusal under paragraph 4.2 (a) and (c) of [Apprendix V  of Immigration Rules](https://www.gov.uk/guidance/immigration-rules/immigration-rules-appendix-v-visitor-rules) which states:

> (a) will leave the UK at the end of their visit;
>
> (c) is genuinely seeking entry for a purpose that is permitted by the visitor routes

The fact that you have to sponsor his entire trip only makes the matter worse, as this sends a strong signal that the person cannot afford the trip they are about to undertake. And what's worse it doesn't help against a refusal under those two paragraphs mentioned above, and unless those two points are satisfied, he will likely be refused.

It's also worth noting that you should never try to hide the fact that you are a couple. While revealing it can potentially put your application under more suspicion, as they may be worried that your partner will decide to stay with you after his visa expires, trying to hide it rarely works and when found out will seriously harm your credibility.

As it seems unlikely that he will be allowed to the UK, and apparently cannot enter the Philippines, have you considered meeting in some other country? If you have the money to fly both of you to some tourist destination, then you should have much easier time obtaining entry clearance there.